# Modelling an input that can be used a finite amount of times along a time horizon and is also binary

Tags: gekko

Happy holidays everyone! I finally have some time off to work on my project, and of course I'm stuck as usual lol.

I'm looking for guidance/examples that would let me be able to model the following:

1. I have an input (lets call it a 'jump') that is binary (0 or 1) and I want it to only be able to be used only once (or possibly a 'n' number of times where n<#time steps) over the entire time horizon. The affect this input has on the system is it will instantaneously increase the velocity of the system by some predetermined amount.
2. The second affect this has on the system is that the set of dynamics that progress the system forward in time change. (In this case the 'jump' will change the dynamics from a driving system to a flying system). In the future there will also be a 'double_jump' that does not change the dynamics but does still provide an instantaneous change in velocity. Currently I'm trying to get the first part down then I'm going to attempt to implement this. Just want to keep my bigger vision clear to anyone reading this.
3. Also another part that is for the future of the model: I'd like to be able to have the system interact with a ball object by let's say using the if2/if3 and if the system's position is some radius from another object's position an impulse will be imparted on the ball object dependent on things like the velocities of the ball and the system. To do properly I imagine I need a way to define a time step that happens at the interaction point, which I believe means I'll need some sort of variable time vector. Any examples for these would be much appreciated.

Okay so 2 and 3 are just here to be here, not really the main points of this question. I think I'll be able to figure them out once I can wrap my head around implementing this weird 'jump' input.

My current plan is to have an MV called 'u_jump' that is a non-integer. Then have a Var called 'jump_hist' that is essentially the 'integral' of 'u_jump', and I give jump_hist an upper bound of 1. What I do right now is just pretend this u_jump is an acceleration on the system by adding to the velocity.dt() equation. This works in theory but doesn't really represent the system I'm trying to control perfectly.

What would be the best example for me to learn some lessons from for implementing this? And another question, is there a way to make the IPOPT solver work for integer solutions by giving the integers a tolerance? Somewhat like the minlp solver option 'minlp_integer_tol 0.05', that way I can still get the speed of IPOPT but the ability to incorporate integer style variables/equations like if3() etc... If not, are there ways I can approach the integer solution with a non-integer solution such that when I implement the control on a real system, the difference between the non-integer solution and the integer solution is within some acceptable tolerance to consider it a disturbance that a feedback controller could mitigate?

Kind of a mouthful I know, my questions always are haha. Hopefully this is helpful for others in the future! Here's my code currently. Let me know if the code gives you issues or anything I could clear up in the question.

Oh and one final note, this is currently setup as a 2D flying system. I've removed the driving dynamics (the c splines commented out) for simplicity of implementing this 'jump' input.

Happy Holidays again everyone!

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
import gekko
from gekko import GEKKO
import csv
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

class Optimizer():
    def __init__(self):
#################GROUND DRIVING OPTIMIZER SETTTINGS##############
        self.d = GEKKO(remote=False) # Driving on ground optimizer

        ntd = 21

        self.d.time = np.linspace(0, 1, ntd) # Time vector normalized 0-1

        # options
        self.d.options.NODES = 3
        self.d.options.SOLVER = 3
        self.d.options.IMODE = 6# MPC mode
        self.d.options.MAX_ITER = 800
        self.d.options.MV_TYPE = 0
        self.d.options.DIAGLEVEL = 0
        # self.d.options.OTOL = 1

        # final time for driving optimizer
        self.tf = self.d.FV(value=1.0,lb=0.1,ub=10.0, name='tf')

        # allow gekko to change the tf value
        self.tf.STATUS = 1
        
        # time variable
        self.t = self.d.Var(value=0)
        self.d.Equation(self.t.dt()/self.tf == 1)

        # Acceleration variable
        self.a = self.d.MV(fixed_initial=False, lb = 0, ub = 1, name='a')
        self.a.STATUS = 1
        
        # Jumping integer varaibles and equations
        self.u_jump = self.d.MV(fixed_initial=False, lb=0, ub=1, integer=True)
        self.u_jump.STATUS = 1
        self.jump_hist = self.d.Var(value=0, name='jump_hist', lb=0, ub=1)
        self.d.Equation(self.jump_hist.dt() == self.u_jump*(ntd-1))
        # self.d.Equation(1.0 >= self.jump_hist)

        # pitch input throttle (rotation of system)
        self.u_p = self.d.MV(fixed_initial=False, lb = -1, ub=1)
        self.u_p.STATUS = 1

        # Final variable that allows you to set an objective function considering only final state
        self.p_d = np.zeros(ntd)
        self.p_d[-1] = 1.0
        self.final = self.d.Param(value = self.p_d, name='final')

        # Model constants and parameters
        self.Dp = self.d.Const(value = 2.7982, name='D_pitch')
        self.Tp = self.d.Const(value = 12.146, name='T_pitch')
        self.pi = self.d.Const(value = 3.14159, name='pi')
        self.g = self.d.Const(value = 0, name='Fg')
        self.jump_magnitude = self.d.Param(value = 3000, name = 'jump_mag')

    def optimize2D(self, si, sf, vi, vf, ri, omegai): #these are 1x2 vectors s or v [x, z]

        # variables and intial conditions 
        # Position in 2d
        self.sx = self.d.Var(value=si[0], lb=-4096, ub=4096, name='x') #x position
        # self.sy = self.d.Var(value=si[1], lb=-5120, ub=5120, name='y') #y position
        self.sz = self.d.Var(value = si[1])

        # Pitch rotation and angular velocity
        self.pitch = self.d.Var(value = ri, name='pitch', lb=-1*self.pi, ub=self.pi)
        self.pitch_dot = self.d.Var(fixed_initial=False, name='pitch_dot')

        # Velocity in 2D
        self.v_mag = self.d.Var(value=(vi), name='v_mag')
        self.vx = self.d.Var(value=np.cos(ri), name='vx') #x velocity
        # self.vy = self.d.Var(value=(np.sin(ri) * vi), name='vy') #y velocity
        self.vz = self.d.Var(value = (np.sin(ri) * vi), name='vz')

## Non-linear state dependent dynamics descired as csplines.
        #curvature vs vel as a cubic spline for driving state
        cur = np.array([0.0069, 0.00398, 0.00235, 0.001375, 0.0011, 0.00088])
        v_cur = np.array([0,500,1000,1500,1750,2300])
        v_cur_fine = np.linspace(0,2300,100)
        cur_fine = np.interp(v_cur_fine, v_cur, cur)
        self.curvature = self.d.Var(name='curvature')
        self.d.cspline(self.v_mag, self.curvature, v_cur_fine, cur_fine)

        # throttle vs vel as cubic spline for driving state
        ba=991.666 #Boost acceleration magnitude
        kv = np.array([0, 1410, 2300]) #velocity input
        ka = np.array([1600+ba, 0+ba, 0+ba]) #acceleration ouput
        kv_fine = np.linspace(0, 2300, 100) # Higher resolution
        ka_fine = np.interp(kv_fine, kv, ka) # Piecewise linear high resolution of ka
        self.throttle_acceleration = self.d.Var(fixed_initial=False, name='throttle_accel')
        self.d.cspline(self.v_mag, self.throttle_acceleration, kv_fine, ka_fine)

# Differental equations
        # Velocity diff eqs
        self.d.Equation(self.vx.dt()/self.tf == (self.a*ba * self.d.cos(self.pitch)*self.jump_hist) + (self.a * self.throttle_acceleration * (1-self.jump_hist)) + (self.u_jump * self.jump_magnitude * self.d.cos(self.pitch + np.pi/2)))
        self.d.Equation(self.vz.dt()/self.tf == (self.a*ba * self.d.sin(self.pitch)*self.jump_hist) - (self.g * (1-self.jump_hist)) + (self.u_jump * self.jump_magnitude * self.d.sin(self.pitch + np.pi/2)))
        self.d.Equation(self.v_mag == self.d.sqrt((self.vx*self.vx) + (self.vz*self.vz)))
        self.d.Equation(2300 >= self.v_mag)

        # Position diff eqs
        self.d.Equation(self.sx.dt()/self.tf == self.vx)
        # self.d.Equation(self.sy.dt()/self.tf == self.vy)
        self.d.Equation(self.sz.dt()/self.tf == self.vz)

        # Orientation diff eqs
        self.d.Equation(self.pitch_dot.dt()/self.tf == ((self.Tp * self.u_p) + (self.Dp * self.pitch_dot * (1 - self.d.abs2(self.u_p)))) * self.jump_hist)
        self.d.Equation(self.pitch.dt()/self.tf == self.pitch_dot)


# Objective functions
        # Final Position Objectives
        self.d.Minimize(self.final*1e2*((self.sz-sf[1])**2)) # z final position objective
        self.d.Minimize(self.final*1e2*((self.sx-sf[0])**2)) # x final position objective
        # Final Velocity Objectives
        # self.d.Obj(self.final*1e3*(self.vz-vf[1])**2)
        # self.d.Obj(self.final*1e3*(self.vx-vf[0])**2)

        # Minimum Time Objective
        self.d.Minimize(1e4*self.tf)

        #solve
        # self.d.solve('http://127.0.0.1') # Solve with local apmonitor server
        self.d.open_folder()
        self.d.solve(disp=True)

        self.ts = np.multiply(self.d.time, self.tf.value[0])

        return self.a, self.u_p, self.ts

    def getTrajectoryData(self):
        return [self.ts, self.sx, self.sz, self.vx, self.vz, self.pitch, self.pitch_dot]

    def getInputData(self):
        return [self.ts, self.a]

# Main Code

opt = Optimizer()

s_ti = [0,0]
v_ti = 0
s_tf = [1000,500]
v_tf = [00.00, 00.0]
r_ti = 0 # inital orientation of the car
omega_ti = 0.0 # initial angular velocity of car

acceleration, turning, t_star = opt.optimize2D(s_ti, s_tf, v_ti, v_tf, r_ti, omega_ti)

# Printing stuff
# print('u', acceleration.value)
# print('tf', opt.tf.value)
# print('tf', opt.tf.value[0])
# print('u jump', opt.jump)
# for i in opt.u_jump: print(i.value)
print('u_jump', opt.u_jump.value)
print('jump his', opt.jump_hist.value)
print('v_mag', opt.v_mag.value)
print('a', opt.a.value)

# Plotting stuff

ts = opt.d.time * opt.tf.value[0]
t_max = opt.tf.value[0]
x_max = np.max(opt.sx.value)
vx_max = np.max(opt.vx.value)
z_max = np.max(opt.sz.value)
vz_max = np.max(opt.vz.value)
# plot results
fig = plt.figure(2)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
# plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
Axes3D.plot(ax, opt.sx.value, ts, opt.sz.value, c='r', marker ='o')
plt.ylim(0, t_max)
plt.xlim(0, x_max)
plt.ylabel('time')
plt.xlabel('Position x')
ax.set_zlabel('position z')

n=5 #num plots
fig = plt.figure(3)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
# plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
Axes3D.plot(ax, opt.vx.value, ts, opt.vz.value,  c='r', marker ='o')
plt.ylim(0, t_max)
plt.xlim(-1*vx_max, vx_max)
# plt.zlim(0, 2000)
plt.ylabel('time')
plt.xlabel('Velocity x')
ax.set_zlabel('vz')

plt.figure(1)
plt.subplot(n,1,1)
plt.plot(ts, opt.a, 'r-')
plt.ylabel('acceleration')

plt.subplot(n,1,2)
plt.plot(ts, np.multiply(opt.pitch, 1/math.pi), 'r-')
plt.ylabel('pitch orientation')

plt.subplot(n, 1, 3)
plt.plot(ts, opt.v_mag, 'b-')
plt.ylabel('vmag')

plt.subplot(n, 1, 4)
plt.plot(ts, opt.u_p, 'b-')
plt.ylabel('u_p')

plt.subplot(n, 1, 5)
plt.plot(ts, opt.u_jump, 'b-')
plt.plot(ts, opt.jump_hist, 'r-')
plt.ylabel('jump(b), jump hist(r)')

plt.show()

print('asdf')
```

Comment: Here are some example problems that may help: https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/MoreDynamicOptimizationBenchmarks  For adjusting the dynamics, you can adjust the time differential that is similar to minimizing the final time.

Answer (score 1):

One thing to try is solve with IPOPT for initialization and then APOPT to get the integer solution. Another thing to try is to use an MPCC for a switching condition that does not rely on a binary variable. I've found the MPCC form to be much less reliable than a binary variable switching condition because the solver often gets stuck at the saddle point. However, integer solutions often take much longer to solve.

```py
self.d.options.SOLVER=3
self.d.solve(disp=True)
self.d.options.TIME_SHIFT=0
self.d.options.SOLVER=1
self.d.solve(disp=True)
```

Here is the solution with IPOPT:

```
EXIT: Optimal Solution Found.

 The solution was found.

 The final value of the objective function is  506284.8987787149
 
 ---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  IPOPT (v3.12)
 Solution time  :  7.4613000000000005 sec
 Objective      :  506284.8987787149
 Successful solution
 ---------------------------------------------------
```

The integer solution is obtained with APOPT.

```
 --------- APM Model Size ------------
 Variable time shift OFF
 Number of state variables:    1286
 Number of total equations: -  1180
 Number of slack variables: -  40
 ---------------------------------------
 Degrees of freedom       :    66
 
 ----------------------------------------------
 Dynamic Control with APOPT Solver
 ----------------------------------------------
Iter:     1 I:  0 Tm:      2.72 NLPi:   92 Dpth:    0 Lvs:    3 Obj:  5.07E+05 Gap:       NaN
Iter:     2 I: -1 Tm:      0.53 NLPi:   17 Dpth:    1 Lvs:    2 Obj:  5.07E+05 Gap:       NaN
Iter:     3 I: -9 Tm:     47.59 NLPi:  801 Dpth:    1 Lvs:    1 Obj:  5.07E+05 Gap:       NaN
Iter:     4 I:  0 Tm:      2.26 NLPi:   35 Dpth:    1 Lvs:    3 Obj:  5.08E+05 Gap:       NaN
--Integer Solution:   2.54E+07 Lowest Leaf:   5.08E+05 Gap:   1.92E+00
Iter:     5 I:  0 Tm:      3.56 NLPi:   32 Dpth:    2 Lvs:    2 Obj:  2.54E+07 Gap:  1.92E+00
Iter:     6 I: -9 Tm:     54.65 NLPi:  801 Dpth:    2 Lvs:    1 Obj:  5.08E+05 Gap:  1.92E+00
Iter:     7 I: -1 Tm:      2.18 NLPi:   83 Dpth:    2 Lvs:    0 Obj:  5.08E+05 Gap:  1.92E+00
 No additional trial points, returning the best integer solution
 Successful solution
 
 ---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  APOPT (v1.0)
 Solution time  :  113.5842 sec
 Objective      :  2.5419931399165962E+7
 Successful solution
 ---------------------------------------------------
```

[image: solution]

APOPT chooses not to jump to minimize the final objective. You may need to add a hard constraint that the `vsum()` of `u_jump` is `1`. There are [additional tutorials on MPCC and integer / binary forms of switching conditions in the Optimization course](https://apmonitor.com/me575/index.php/Main/LogicalConditions).

Thanks for sharing your application and keep us updated!

Comment: Thank you John. I'm going to read up one this and see if I can get a better solution. I think approximating the instantaneous velocity increase as just a high acceleration or "jerk" might be enough to let me use a feedback controller to approach the optimal trajectory but I still have some other things to model using GEKKO. Actually i'm going to post another question soon regarding applying diff eqs onto a differential manifold defined by a list of points and manifold normals. But that's another question. I'm still formulating the problem before I post but it'll be up soon! Thanks again!